# Reentrant caching of "referentially transparent" IO calls

Tags: haskell, concurrency, memoization

Assume we have an IO action such as

```
lookupStuff :: InputType -> IO OutputType
```

which could be something simple such as DNS lookup, or some web-service call against a time-invariant data.

Let's assume that:

1. The operation never throws any exception and/or never diverges
2. If it wasn't for the `IO` monad, the function would be pure, i.e. the result is always the same for equal input parameters
3. The action is reentrant, i.e. it can be called from multiple threads at the same time safely.
4. The `lookupStuff` operation is quite (time-)expensive.

The problem I'm facing is how to properly (and w/o using any `unsafe*IO*` cheat) implement a reentrant cache, that can be called from multiple threads, and coalesces multiple queries for the same input-parameters into a single request.

I guess I'm after something similiar as GHC's blackhole-concept for pure computations but in the IO "calculation" context.

What is the idiomatic Haskell/GHC solution for the stated problem?

Comment: The assumptions 1, 2 and 3 seem to imply that the function is really pure and the impurity is merely an implementation detail.  In that case, I do not think that there is anything wrong with using unsafePerformIO.  In fact, I think that unsafePerformIO exists exactly for such cases.

Comment: Agreed. 1, 2, 3 are very strong assumptions that almost never hold for code in IO, but if in fact you can guarantee this unsafePerformIO is fairly reasonable.

Comment: Ok, but how do I guarantee that the IO effect is never performed more than once for the same input-argument?

Comment: You'll need to memoize the pure structure for that, but there's plenty of literature on how to do that. (Note that you can also memoize the IO structure as well, in a more traditional imperative manner)

Comment: How can you be assured that a web service call, say, will never diverge? What if there's a problem with the network? Though I'm not sure this is -necessarily- a requirement, pure functions are allowed (if not exactly encouraged) to diverge.

Comment: Though if I'm reading your question correctly, it's not a requirement that the lookup function be pure? I'd be kind of queasy about putting a web service call inside unsafePerformIO, however time-invariant it's presumed to be.

Comment: the assumption about non-diverging is just for simplicity to keep exception handling out of the picture

Comment: Personally, I don't see how constraint #1 can be guaranteed in actuality, unless the function doesn't actually perform IO.

Comment: For instance, the IO action could be wrapped in an exception handler which would transform any exception into a fallback value...?

Answer (score 5):

Yeah, basically reimplement the logic.  Although it seems similar to what GHC is already doing, that's GHC's choice.  Haskell can be implemented on VMs that work very differently, so in that sense it isn't already done for you.

But yeah, just use an `MVar (Map InputType OutputType)` or even an `IORef (Map InputType OutputType)` (make sure to modify with `atomicModifyIORef`), and just store the cache in there.  If this imperative solution seems wrong, it's the "if not for the `IO`, this function would be pure" constraint.  If it were just an arbitrary `IO` action, then the idea that you would have to keep state in order to know what to execute or not seems perfectly natural.  The problem is that Haskell does not have a type for "pure IO" (which, if it depends on a database, it is just behaving pure under certain conditions, which is not the same as being a hereditarily pure).

```
import qualified Data.Map as Map
import Control.Concurrent.MVar

-- takes an IO function and returns a cached version
cache :: (Ord a) => (a -> IO b) -> IO (a -> IO b)
cache f = do
    r <- newMVar Map.empty
    return $ \x -> do
        cacheMap <- takeMVar r
        case Map.lookup x cacheMap of
            Just y -> do 
                putMVar r cacheMap
                return y
            Nothing -> do
                y <- f x
                putMVar (Map.insert x y cacheMap)
                return y
```

Yeah it's ugly on the inside.  But on the outside, look at that!  It's just like the type of a pure memoization function, except for it has `IO` stained all over it.

Comment: Mind, as implemented, this is a synchronized cache.  I.e. every call to it is blocked by an `MVar`.  The alternative is possibly allowing the same action to run more than once.  Then I would use an `IORef` instead, and `atomicModifyIORef`.

Comment: Indeed, this is the semantically sound approach. You can always put an `unsafePerformIO` around the results if you are so included.

Comment: Well, it seems your implementation serializes the IO function calls, even if the `cache`-wrapped function is invoked concurrently from different threads. How would you make it non-serialized but w/o allowing to run the "same" action more than once?

Comment: @hvr, Oh I see why you were talking about black holes.  So you only want to block if that same key is already being evaluated.  You'd have to have a lock for each input value, I think, so your state would look like `Map.Map InputType (MVar OutputType)`, where the `MVar` is empty if it is currently evaluating, and the entry is not in the map if it is not.  And then you should use an `MVar` to store that map so that you don't get race conditions.  Basically -- all the usual concurrent programming garbage. `IO` *means* imperative programming.  You just try to minimize its extent.

Answer (score 3):

Here's some code implementing more or less what I was after in my original question:

```
import           Control.Concurrent
import           Control.Exception
import           Data.Either
import           Data.Map           (Map)
import qualified Data.Map           as Map
import           Prelude            hiding (catch)

-- |Memoizing wrapper for 'IO' actions
memoizeIO :: Ord a => (a -> IO b) -> IO (a -> IO b)
memoizeIO action = do
  cache <- newMVar Map.empty
  return $ memolup cache action

  where
    -- Lookup helper
    memolup :: Ord a => MVar (Map a (Async b)) -> (a -> IO b) -> a -> IO b
    memolup cache action' args = wait' =<< modifyMVar cache lup
      where
        lup tab = case Map.lookup args tab of
          Just ares' ->
            return (tab, ares')
          Nothing    -> do
            ares' <- async $ action' args
            return (Map.insert args ares' tab, ares')
```

The code above builds upon Simon Marlow's `Async` abstraction as described in [Tutorial: Parallel and Concurrent Programming in Haskell](http://community.haskell.org/~simonmar/par-tutorial.pdf):

```
-- |Opaque type representing asynchronous results.
data Async a = Async ThreadId (MVar (Either SomeException a))

-- |Construct 'Async' result. Can be waited on with 'wait'.
async :: IO a -> IO (Async a)
async io = do
  var <- newEmptyMVar
  tid <- forkIO ((do r <- io; putMVar var (Right r))
                 `catch` \e -> putMVar var (Left e))
  return $ Async tid var

-- |Extract value from asynchronous result. May block if result is not
-- available yet. Exceptions are returned as 'Left' values.
wait :: Async a -> IO (Either SomeException a)
wait (Async _ m) = readMVar m

-- |Version of 'wait' that raises exception.
wait' :: Async a -> IO a
wait' a = either throw return =<< wait a

-- |Cancels asynchronous computation if not yet completed (non-blocking).
cancel :: Async a -> IO ()
cancel (Async t _) = throwTo t ThreadKilled
```

Comment: Very nice! Do you foresee any problems replacing Data.Map with HashMap?

Comment: @circular-ruin, can't think of any

Comment: Wait: what happens if I pass call the memoized function using a thunk as input? AFAICS the global MVar (the one that protects the whole table, rather than the little ones protecting the individual values) will be held for the whole time it takes to resolve the thunk to something unthunk-y enough to find its place in the table. Will this not block all other threads from using the memo table, undermining the 'free of unnecessary locks' philosophy you seem to be going for?

Comment: Ah, but I guess you probably don't mind because in your application you're willing to deem any pure computation (i.e. non-IO monad operation) as 'cheap'  :-)

Comment: more or less, I deem the lookup/update operation on the table as rather cheap, therefore an efficient `HashMap` should be even better for large caches; one could add a fast-path lookup-try w/o locking as a first attempt, before going into the current mutexed lookup w/o risking incorrectness-causing race-conditions -- but I have no idea how expensive the execution of the `modifyMVar` call above really is... it should really be benchmarked before deciding which approach to take