# Is there an object-identity-based, thread-safe memoization library somewhere?

Tags: haskell, memoization

I know that memoization seems to be a perennial topic here on the haskell tag on stack overflow, but I *think* this question has not been asked before.

I'm aware of several different 'off the shelf' memoization libraries for Haskell:

- The memo-combinators and memotrie packages, which make use of a beautiful trick involving lazy infinite data structures to achieve memoization in a purely functional way. (As I understand it, the former is slightly more flexible, while the latter is easier to use in simple cases: see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980102/how-does-data-memocombinators-work/4980838#4980838) for discussion.)
- The uglymemo package, which uses unsafePerformIO internally but still presents a referentially transparent interface. The use of unsafePerformIO internally results in [better performance](http://augustss.blogspot.com/2011/04/ugly-memoization-heres-problem-that-i.html) than the previous two packages. (Off the shelf, its implementation uses comparison-based search data structures, rather than perhaps-slightly-more-efficient hash functions; but I think that if you find and replace `Cmp` for `Hashable` and `Data.Map` for `Data.HashMap` and add the appropraite `import`s, you get a hash based version.)

However, I'm not aware of any library that looks answers up based on *object identity* rather than *object value*. This can be important, because sometimes the kinds of object which are being used as keys to your memo table (that is, as input to the function being memoized) can be large---so large that fully examining the object to determine whether you've seen it before is itself a slow operation. Slow, and also unnecessary, if you will be applying the memoized function again and again to an object which is stored at a given 'location in memory' [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980102/how-does-data-memocombinators-work/4980838#4980838). (This might happen, for example, if we're memoizing a function which is being called recursively over some large data structure with a lot of structural sharing.) If we've already computed our memoized function on that exact object before, we can already know the answer, even without looking at the object itself!

Implementing such a memoization library involves several subtle issues and doing it properly requires several special pieces of support from the language. Luckily, GHC provides all the special features that we need, and there is a [paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.34.1948) by Peyton-Jones, Marlow and Elliott which basically worries about most of these issues for you, explaining how to build a solid implementation. They don't provide all details, but they get close.

The one detail which I can see which one probably ought to worry about, but which they *don't* worry about, is thread safety---their code is apparently not threadsafe at all.

My question is: does anyone know of a packaged library which does the kind of memoization discussed in the Peyton-Jones, Marlow and Elliott paper, filling in all the details (and preferably filling in proper thread-safety as well)?

Failing that, I guess I will have to code it up myself: does anyone have any ideas of *other* subtleties (beyond thread safety and the ones discussed in the paper) which the implementer of such a library would do well to bear in mind?

---

**UPDATE**

Following @luqui's suggestion below, here's a little more data on the exact problem I face. Let's suppose there's a type:

```
data Node = Node [Node] [Annotation]
```

This type can be used to represent a simple kind of rooted DAG in memory, where `Node`s are DAG Nodes, the root is just a distinguished `Node`, and each node is annotated with some `Annotation`s whose internal structure, I think, need not concern us (but if it matters, just ask and I'll be more specific.) If used in this way, note that there may well be significant structural sharing between `Node`s in memory---there may be exponentially more paths which lead from the root to a node than there are nodes themselves. I am given a data structure of this form, from an external library with which I must interface; I cannot change the data type.

I have a function

```
myTransform : Node -> Node
```

the details of which need not concern us (or at least I think so; but again I can be more specific if needed). It maps nodes to nodes, examining the annotations of the node it is given, and the annotations its immediate children, to come up with a new `Node` with the same children but possibly different annotations. I wish to write a function

```
recursiveTransform : Node -> Node
```

whose output 'looks the same' as the data structure as you would get by doing:

```
recursiveTransform Node originalChildren annotations = 
   myTransform Node recursivelyTransformedChildren annotations
   where
     recursivelyTransformedChildren = map recursiveTransform originalChildren
```

except that it uses structural sharing in the obvious way so that it doesn't return an exponential data structure, but rather one on the order of the same size as its input.

I appreciate that this would all be easier if say, the `Nodes` were numbered before I got them, or I could otherwise change the definition of a `Node`. I can't (easily) do either of these things.

---

I am also interested in the general question of the existence of a library implementing the functionality I mention quite independently of the particular concrete problem I face right now: I feel like I've had to work around this kind of issue on a few occasions, and it would be nice to slay the dragon once and for all. The fact that SPJ et al felt that it was worth adding not one but three features to GHC to support the existence of libraries of this form suggests that the feature is genuinely useful and can't be worked around in *all* cases. (BUT I'd still also be very interested in hearing about workarounds which will help in this particular case too: the long term problem is not as urgent as the problem I face right now :-) )

[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980102/how-does-data-memocombinators-work/4980838#4980838) Technically, I don't quite mean location in memory, since the garbage collector sometimes moves objects around a bit---what I really mean is 'object identity'. But we can think of this as being roughly the same as our intuitive idea of location in memory.

Comment: Are you familiar with [using `StableName`s?](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.3.1.0/doc/html/System-Mem-StableName.html)

Comment: @C. A. McCann: Yes, the use of StableNames in implementing such a library is discussed in depth in the paper I link to. (Indeed, maybe that paper was the first appearance of StableNames in print? I could be wrong about that though!)

Comment: Entirely possible. There tends to be a pretty direct correspondence between "GHC features" and "papers listing SPJ as an author". Mostly wanted to know because you didn't mention `StableName` directly, even though (I think) it provides the pseudo-pointer equality primitive you want. So it's just the memoizer itself you need.

Comment: @C. A. McCann: Yes, they even basically write the memoizer, modulo a hash table, in the paper. (And a hash table is easy to find in a library.) I'd just (a) rather avoid typing in the code from the paper and (b) rather avoid the possibility of making a silly mistake as I make things threadsafe. I thought I *couldn't* be the first person to need this :)

Comment: Ok. Thanks for clarifying. And no, I'm not aware of any existing implementations, sorry! There very well could be something to do the trick on Hackage under a less-than-obvious name though.

Comment: btw, `uglymemo` assumes single-threaded accesses and thus is inferior to the other two packages

Comment: @hvr: Is that true? I thought it remained correct in multi-threaded applications, with the only caveat being a residual chance that a given function-value would be computed twice in different threads. The reason I thought that was the discussion in the blog post I link  to in the question (on the words 'better performance'), which seems to engage with thread safety quite specifically. Are there particular circumstances you can see where it is not threadsafe?

Comment: @circular-ruin: Yes, I'm actually referring to the behavior that the same computation may be evaluated multiple times when used in a highly parallel scenario , which IMHO defeats the purpose of memoization in the first place, especially if the computations involved take a significant time, the chance to request the same computation again before the previous computation has finished becomes non-negligible; But is is possible (I've done it) to code `uglymemo` in a way which queues requests for computation which are already in progress w/o blocking the whole lookup-dictionary

Comment: @circular-ruin: See my self-answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484847/reentrant-caching-of-referentially-transparent-io-calls for an example of how to code up `uglymemo` taking into account concurrent accesses w/o causing duplicate compuations/effects

Comment: @hvr: Thanks, very interesting! Your question and the answers are very helpful: I missed them in my search of old questions because I looked only for 'memo', not for 'caching'. If I end up having to code this myself, I'll be sure to try to follow your example in making this fully reentrant.

Comment: Related: [Type-Safe Observable Sharing in Haskell](http://www.ittc.ku.edu/csdl/fpg/sites/default/files/Gill-09-TypeSafeReification.pdf), although it uses `StableNames` and does not seem to address thread-safety.

Comment: @hammar---Thanks, very interesting. I'll be sure to look through the paper. I guess I think it's impossible to do what I need without `StableNames`, so I'm not so worried about them being used, but the lack of thread safety is not so good for me.

Answer (score 6):

If you *only* want to memoize based on object identity, and not equality, you can just use the existing laziness mechanisms built into the language.

For example, if you have a data structure like this

```
data Foo = Foo { ... }
expensive :: Foo -> Bar
```

then you can just add the value to be memoized as an extra field and let the laziness take care of the rest for you.

```
data Foo = Foo { ..., memo :: Bar }
```

To make it easier to use, add a smart constructor to tie the knot.

```
makeFoo ... = let foo = Foo { ..., memo = expensive foo } in foo
```

Though this is somewhat less elegant than using a library, and requires modification of the data type to really be useful, it's a very simple technique and all thread-safety issues are already taken care of for you.

Comment: It seems like this approach cannot help unless one is willing and able to modify the type which will be used as key (=input to the function you wish to memoize). That is not the case for me. Am I missing something?

Comment: Although *if* one does happen to be in that case, this is more efficient, saving you map lookup per evaluation.

Comment: You can store the memoized value in a wrapper type, though you'll have to lift your existing computations (at least the ones that need to consume the memoized value) to work on the wrapped type instead, i.e. something like `data MemoFoo = MemoFoo Foo Bar`, with `makeFoo ... = let foo = Foo { ... } in MemoFoo foo (expensive foo)`.

Comment: If I'm trying to write a function `f :: Foo -> Bar`, and I (as you suggest) construct a wrapper type `MemoFoo` which contains two fields, a field to contain a `Foo` and a `memo` field containing a `Bar`, then I'm still confused about the following: what does `f` do (having been given a `Foo`) to find its associated `MemoFoo` object (if it has one)?

Comment: You can't. That's what I meant with lifting. `f` has to be changed to `f :: MemoFoo -> Bar`. You'll have to change the data type if you need recursive memoization, though.

Comment: OK. I think, alas, that this approach is not going to help with what I need. I need to, at the end of the day, produce a function of type `Foo->Bar`.

Comment: @circular-ruin, maybe you could elaborate on your goal and your constraints so we can help you solve this problem.  Maybe there is an approach you haven't thought of...

Answer (score 3):

It seems that [stable-memo](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/stable-memo) would be just what you needed (although I'm not sure if it can handle multiple threads):

> Whereas most memo combinators memoize based on equality, stable-memo does it based on whether the exact same argument has been passed to the function before (that is, is the same argument in memory).
>
> - stable-memo only evaluates keys to WHNF.
> - This can be more suitable for recursive functions over graphs with cycles.
> - stable-memo doesn't retain the keys it has seen so far, which allows them to be garbage collected if they will no longer be used. Finalizers are put in place to remove the corresponding entries from the memo table if this happens.
> - Data.StableMemo.Weak provides an alternative set of combinators that also avoid retaining the results of the function, only reusing results if they have not yet been garbage collected.
> - There is no type class constraint on the function's argument.
>
> stable-memo will not work for arguments which happen to have the same value but are not the same heap object. This rules out many candidates for memoization, such as the most common example, the naive Fibonacci implementation whose domain is machine Ints; it can still be made to work for some domains, though, such as the lazy naturals.

Answer (score 1):

Ekmett just uploaded a library that handles this and more (produced at HacPhi): http://hackage.haskell.org/package/intern. He assures me that it is thread safe.

Edit: Actually, strictly speaking I realize this does something rather different. But I think you can use it for your purposes. It's really more of a stringtable-atom type interning library that works over arbitrary data structures (including recursive ones). It uses WeakPtrs internally to maintain the table. However, it uses `Int`s to index the values to avoid structural equality checks, which means packing them into the data type, when what you want are apparently actually `StableName`s. So I realize this answers a related question, but requires modifying your data type, which you want to avoid...

Comment: Excellent! Very interesting :). I'm just looking at it now. I'm probably being a bit dense, but it's not clear to me how to use this as a memoization library. (It does seem to immediately answer my other question about string interning!) If I want to write `memoize:: (a->b)->(a->b)`, how do I go about it? (I'm also confused because it doesn't seem to use `StableNames`, which I thought were essential...) Anyway, sorry for being stupid!

Comment: See my edit above -- I just realized why this doesn't suit your request.

Comment: Nonetheless, a great feat of hacking! I actually have another question on SO somewhere asking about interning strings and so on, in which the lack of a proper thread-safe interning library came up: so perhaps you would like to post this as an answer there so I can vote it up :).