# Test IORef identity?

Tags: haskell

In Haskell, is there a way to test whether two IORefs are identical? I'm looking for something like this:

```
IORef a -> IORef a -> IO Bool
```

This would be useful if you want to visualize a graph made of IORefs, for example. I don't think it would break referential transparency, because IORefs have a meaningful identity (and the result could be in IO, anyway). And I assume it wouldn't be hard to implement this efficiently, as a pointer comparison.

Is this available somewhere? Or if not, why not?

(Edit: I just found [System.Mem.StableName](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.3.1.0/docs/System-Mem-StableName.html) from [a different SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6878193/is-there-an-object-identity-based-thread-safe-memoization-library-somewhere), which looks helpful.)

Comment: [It's called `(==)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-IORef.html#t:IORef)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't overthink it. You have [`instance Eq (IORef a)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-IORef.html#t:IORef), so you can just use `==`, and the result isn't even in `IO`.

Comment: Note that this is identity for `IORef`s, but you may of course have multiple distinct `IORef`s pointing to the same actual *value*, that is, the normal non-observable sharing of Haskell references

Comment: Thanks, not sure how I missed that. :)